# Target specific packages in Cargo workspace

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to include cargo packages in the workspace conditionally or tell cargo inside the package Cargo.toml file to ignore them?

Let's say I have a workspace with packages, which should be compiled only on a suitable platform.

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "main",
    "lib_common",
    "lib_linux_only",
    "lib_macos_only",
]
```

All lib pakages are dynamic libraries, so it's OK that some of them won't build on all platforms  (because the main executable will know at runtime which of them to load or not). But it should happen "silently".

In the platform specific modules I have a conditional compilation check like

```
#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
compile_error!("This feature requires Linux");
```

that means I cannot run the main executable because the platform specific packages cannot be built. I have to comment out the linux package on mac and the mac package on linux in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Seems that there is no elegant way of doing this right now. Checkout this unresolved [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5220) that keeps track of this feature request.

Comment: please read this article then try to edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

#### `per-package-target`

With the unstable (as of 2023 July) `per-package-target` feature, it is possible to set the target, which the the package will always compiled for. [Here is the description.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#per-package-target)

#### Not using Cargo Workspace

A [commenter on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/14x9q0p/comment/jrm96d4/) advices using a monorepo instead of the Cargo Workspaces:

> In the end, I stopped using the workspace and just had a monorepo with crates depending on each other.
> [...]
>
> You can force a specific target for a specific crate by using .cargo/config.toml, but Rust Analyzer then assumes that all crates in that workspace use this target, which fails when including stuff like web-sys on native or tokio on wasm.
>
> When using a monorepo, you can include other crates of the same repo with a path entry in Cargo.toml using a relative path. This makes sure that the crates are always compatible with each other, because they have a common commit chain.
>
> In vscode, I then open up every crate on its own as part of a common vscode workspace (which is a different thing than a Cargo workspace!), not the git root directory. This does work correctly.

On top of this, one can use [target specific dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies) (or [development-](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#development-dependencies) and [build dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#build-dependencies)) to achieve what you seek.

PS: I am just getting my project to this complexity so I have yet to test these approaches.